# Cisco ASA ipsec vs Anyconnect client issue

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa, ipsec, anyconnect

So I have an iPad that has a IPSec VPN created. I am able to connect from the outside fine and I can access my local LAN files just fine.  When I connect with the Cisco AnyConnect client from the same device, it allows me to login but I can't access any LAN resources at all, or any external resources either until I disconnect the AnyConnect VPN connection. Can anyone help me understand where I need to look on the ASA to correct this, or have any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Are they using the same or different IP pools? How about you post some configuration snippets?

Comment: I guess that's part of my issue, I'm not sure where to set the IP pools for the different methods of connecting.  I do know when I connect via anyconnect I'm getting an IP address from my local subnet that I didn't specify in the IP pool that I do pull from when connecting to the IPSec, here is my messy setup:

Comment: here is my messy setup: http://jajuka.net/files/config.txt

Comment: When you use Anyconnect, are you referencing the same group as when you use the IPSec connection?

Comment: Do anyconenct clients get IPs from the defined pool?10.2.12.151-10.2.12.250. can you see any log messages from the firewall while the users are connected to the anyconnect VPN?

Comment: Gerry, No for whatever reason it doesn't give them an IP from the pool created, it gives them a normal DHCP lease from the local LAN, though I can't see where I set that up in the config

Comment: SpacemanSpiff, Yes I'm referencing the same group for both, honestly I didnt know there was a difference, I'm coming from a Sonicwall SSLVPN/NSA world hehe, should I create a new group and if so where in the config?  I'm using the ASDM but could use the terminal if needed

Comment: Richard, do you still need help or is this resolved?